# Calling sqoop in pig script

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, sqoop

I wanted to call sqoop export command in my pig script, Basically once I stored my result immediatlyy i wanted to call sqoop export cmd. Is it possible ? If Yes please let me know how to call .

Thanks
Selvam

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do Sqoop export from Apache Pig. Most likely you need to use [HCatStorer](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-Win-1.1/ds_HCatalog/api/org/apache/hcatalog/pig/HCatStorer.html) of HCatalog project. Then you can set the HCatalog table with the HCatalog export option in Apache Sqoop. But I haven't done this before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to run such workflow periodically or just one time? I'm assuming that it's not one time as then it would be very easy to just call Sqoop after the Pig script. I would recommend you taking a look into [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) for automating workflows with multiple steps. If you do not prefer writing the workflow XML yourself, take a look at [Hue Oozie App](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/51101760198/tutorial-a-new-ui-for-oozie) that is extremely user friendly.